# An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred, using ReadAsync

Tags: vb.net, sockets, async-await

*Background:* I am using Visual Basic, with VS Community 2013.  I am making a Windows Forms application. The use case is: user clicks a button. This makes a dialog pop up. Then a TCP client connects to a remote server, and waits for messages to arrive from the server.  Each time a message arrives, text is displayed on the dialog.  If the remote side closes the socket, the dialog should be closed. Additionally, the user can click a button on the dialog which should close the socket and close the dialog.

My code seems to achieve all of that except the last requirement. When the user clicks the button to close the dialog, I get the usual exception popup, with the text:

```
An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.
Additional information: One or more errors occurred.
```

Selecting 'Break' shows that the condition `T.Result = 0` is highlighted. The debugger shows the value of `T` is `Id = 1, Status = Faulted {7}, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"`

My question is: What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

---

Here are the relevant parts of the dialog's code. I have omitted the function `ShowStatus` for brevity, it does nothing other than update visual controls on the form.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text

Public Class FormMyDialog
    Private gRequest As String
    Private inbuf(10000) As Byte
    Private inoff As Integer
    Private serv As NetworkStream
    Private sock As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

    ' the main form calls this when the user clicks a button
    Public Sub Go(request As String)
        gRequest = request
        ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    ' this is the Close button I have placed on the dialog
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        sock.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormMyDialog_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        sock = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
        ShowStatus("Connecting")
        sock.Connect("127.0.0.1", 53000)
        ShowStatus("Connected")

        serv = sock.GetStream()

        Dim outbuf As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(gRequest + Chr(10))
        serv.Write(outbuf, 0, outbuf.Length)
        serv.Flush()

        inoff = 0
        ReadLoop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadLoop()
        Dim readlen As Integer
        Dim T As Task(Of Integer)
        T = serv.ReadAsync(inbuf, inoff, inbuf.Length - inoff)
        If T.Result = 0 Then
            sock.Close()
            Dim d As MethodNoArgs(Of Object)
            d = AddressOf Me.Close
            Me.Invoke(d)
            Return
        End If

        readlen = T.Result
        inoff = inoff + readlen
        ProcessInbuf()
        T.ContinueWith(Sub() ReadLoop())
    End Sub

    Public Delegate Sub MethodNoArgs(Of T1)()

    Private Sub ProcessInbuf()
        ' (omitted) processing that calls ShowStatus
        ' and updates inbuf and inoff
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That exception is a wrapper for other exceptions.  Please examine the exception while debugging and give us the real exceptions inside it.  They will be in the `InnerExceptions` property.

Comment: OK, I used a `Try` and found that there was actually only one exception inside the `AggregateException`:  `{"Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'."}`. I guess this occurs due to me calling `sock.Close()` while `sock.ReadAsync` is in progress, but I don't know how to fix this (and still close the socket)

Comment: I guess I could just catch the exception and continue but that seems untidy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already noticed that the `AggregateException` is just a wrapper around multiple possible exceptions that occurred.

I am not absolutely sure why this functions are failing, but it may be caused by the strange structure of your code. The main problem I see is that you don't follow a clean `async`-`await` structure. Normally you don't need to mess around with `ContinueWith` and `.Result` do get what you want to do here.

The key is to use `await` keyword. This keyword basically combines `ContinueWith` and `.Result`. It means it waits non-blocking until the asynchronous operation is completed and returns the result.

You code actually could be boiled down to something like this:

```
Private Async Sub ReadLoop()
    Dim readlen As Integer

    Do
        readlen = Await serv.ReadAsync(inbuf, inoff, inbuf.Length - inoff)
        inoff = inoff + readlen
        ProcessInbuf() 
        'maybe this should be async too, to wait until the processing is done
    Loop While readlen > 0

    sock.Close()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Another advantage of using `Await` is that it also unwraps the `AggregateException`. You only have to make sure that you handle the exceptions properly, because a `Async Sub` may terminate due to a exception and does not return the exception to the outer class. This happens once it passed the first `Await`. But your code as the same "problem" once it passed the `ContinueWith`.

Comment: How did that happen O.O. Sorry. Fixed it

Comment: OK... progress, your code runs similarly to what I had before but it's tidier.  Now , when I click the cancel button (i.e. call `sock.Close()`), I get a normal-looking exception instead of the AggregateException. The exception is still `{"Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'."}` .

Comment: When my other code calls this Async version of `ReadLoop` for the first time, is it launched in its own thread?  (otherwise, I don't understand how my UI remains responsive)

Comment: All the code up there runs in the same thread. That is the UI thread of the form. This is required so you can interact with the form (update status, close the form, etc.). The thing about `Await` is that it restores the Context it is running in. So it actually syncs back to the UI thread it left for the read operation. If you close your socket outside of the loop it will throw the error of cause. So if this is a valid case you should catch the exception and exit the reading method. Alternatively you could set a cancel flag that is queried in the reading operation and exit the reading loop.

Comment: OK, I see that `Await` causes the thread to jump back to the `FormMyDialog_Shown` function, after the call to `ReadLoop`. How does this thread 'know' to abort whatever else it might end up doing and resume inside `ReadLoop` when data arrives?

Comment: The `ReadLoop` continues upon any event on the IO stream it waits on using `ReadAsync`. Those events may be the arrival of data or the closing of the stream.

Comment: sorry, I mean what happens to whatever was executing in the rest of the program when this event occurs? E.g. let's say that in the `FormMyDialog_Shown` function, after ReadLoop returns I go and factor some large primes

Comment: I've dealt with the annoying exception by doing `Try` `readlen = Await serv.ReadAsync(.....)` `Catch ex As Exception` `readlen = 0` `End Try` , it seems to work. Thanks for the assistance.  This solution had an unexpected bonus too: with my original code, in `ProcessInbuf` I had to use a trick to allow it to update UI controls since it was in a different thread; but with the Async/Await solution I no longer need to do that

Comment: Be careful! This is non-blocking code. The `ReadLoop` will exit once it reaches `Await` for the first time. If you want to await the termination of the `ReadLoop` you need to change it to a `Async Function`.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be non-blocking. I don't understand what happens to whatever else was executing when the `Await` returns. It seems a bit odd if execution can just disappear at some random point and resume back at the Await.